# Abrir modal popup em outro arquivo .cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

ArquivoPai.cshtml encontra-se da seguinte maneira:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <!-- Nesta div pretendo abrir minha popup -->
    <div id="popup"></div>

    <!-- Com este link pretendo acionar a abertura da popup -->
    <a id="open">Abrir PopUp</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#open").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Usuario/arquivoFilho',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#popup').html(data);
                    $('#popup').show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como estou trabalhando com ASP.NET MVC, quando escrevo: `url: "'/Usuario/arquivoFilho',"` no método `$ajax()`, estou dizendo que possuo um controller de nome usuario e dentro dele uma Action (função/método) chamada arquivoFilho, a qual se encontra da seguinte maneira:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class UsuarioController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult arquivoFilho()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Esta ação `arquivoFilho()`, redireciona por padrão para a view "arquivoFilho.cshtml" (Este redirecionamento acontece porque criei a view a partir do método), que possui o conteúdo que pretendo exibir na popup. O arquivo "arquivoFilho.cshtml" encontrase da seguinte maneira:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Editar Usuário</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Usuario", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
        FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.login)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.login)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.login)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.login)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.senha)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.senha)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.senha)
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

O fato é que não está funcionando.

Comment: coloque mais detalhes para que possamos entender se está ocorrendo algum erro de javascript ou na sua ação EditUsuario

Comment: Blz Tiago Silva, vou tentar o alert().

Comment: Fiz a pouco uma reedição do meu problema com um pouco mais de detalhes.

Comment: Oi, Michell, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. A formatação aqui é com Markdown, confira o guia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Michell, se você chamar a URL /Usuario/arquivoFilho diretamente no browser funciona? Caso sim, imagino que o problema possa ser na sua View, pois a mesma retorna um HTML completo que é, posteriormente, incluído dentro de um container (DIV) HTML. Como você está tentando incluir o conteúdo completo (que possui a tag HTML) podem ocorrer erros de formatação HTML. Sugiro que você altere a sua VIEW da seguinte forma:

```
<h2>Editar Usuário</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Usuario", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
    FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.login)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.login)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.login)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.login)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.senha)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.senha)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.senha)
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
}
```